# Stop toad from putting the drop at the top of the view script

Tags: oracle, toad

When I create a view with (example)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MY_VIEW( COL_A, COL_B) AS
SELECT COL_A, COL_B FROM MY_TABLE;
```

And then use toad to generate the script, it always sticks the drop on top.

```
DROP VIEW MY_VIEW;

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MY_VIEW( COL_A, COL_B) AS
SELECT COL_A, COL_B FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Is there a way to tell Toad to stop putting the drop on top?

Since it's doing create or REPLACE anyway, it's useless.
If you run the toad script somewhere where the view does not already exist, it throws an error trying to perform the useless drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right click on the object and select 'create script'

you then have the option to

click on the 'script options' tab and deselect the Drop statement check box

Answer (score 1):

In Toad 9.7 and many other versions try this

- click on the view tab
- select the view
- on the right side select the Script tab
- at the top of the script tab there is a disk drive icon with the tooltip "View/Edit script options"
- click on this icon, under the Common tab there are options for Schema name and Drop Statement. Uncheck the Drop statement